# Naming columns in pandas deletes data

Tags: python, pandas

The code below gives me this table:

```
raw = pd.read_clipboard()
raw.head()

+---+---------------------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   |     Afghanistan     | South Asia  | 652225  | 26000000 | Unnamed: 4  |
+---+---------------------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| 0 | Albania             | Europe      |   28728 |  3200000 | 6656000000  |
| 1 | Algeria             | Middle East | 2400000 | 32900000 | 75012000000 |
| 2 | Andorra             | Europe      |     468 |    64000 | NaN         |
| 3 | Angola              | Africa      | 1250000 | 14500000 | 14935000000 |
| 4 | Antigua and Barbuda | Americas    |     442 |    77000 | 770000000   |
+---+---------------------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

But when I attempt to rename the columns and create a DataFrame, all of the data disappears:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raw, columns = ['name', 'region', 'area', 'population', 'gdp'])
df.head()

+---+------+--------+------+------------+-----+
|   | name | region | area | population | gdp |
+---+------+--------+------+------------+-----+
| 0 | NaN  | NaN    | NaN  | NaN        | NaN |
| 1 | NaN  | NaN    | NaN  | NaN        | NaN |
| 2 | NaN  | NaN    | NaN  | NaN        | NaN |
| 3 | NaN  | NaN    | NaN  | NaN        | NaN |
| 4 | NaN  | NaN    | NaN  | NaN        | NaN |
+---+------+--------+------+------------+-----+
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Why are you making a new DataFrame instead of just doing `df.columns = ['name', 'region', ...]`?  Also, it looks like your data has no header, so the initial read is reading the first row as column names.  Might want to fix that by passing `header=None` to `read_clipboard`.

Comment: This fixes my problems.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You should just write:

```
df.columns = ['name', 'region', ...]
```

This is also much more efficient as you aren't trying to copy the entire DataFrame; as far as I know passing one DataFrame into the constructor for another will make a deep, not shallow copy.